# How to algebraically calculate the difference in days for an inverse-proportion or more people=worse problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> During a drought, 50 people have only $1000 \mathrm{~L}$ of water left. If every person consumes an identical amount of water, the 1000-liter supply would be exhausted in one day. If 40 people were to leave, how much longer (in days) would the water supply last?

I noticed people*days=constant. Why is that true in these more people is worse problems?

For example, 1 person can last on 1000L on fifty days,
but 40 people can last on 1000L for 5/4 days.

Clearly you only gain 1/4 of a day.

This doesn't make sense because the answer key says 40 people can last 4 more days than 50 people on 1000L.

Comment: Why did you set $5/4 - 1 = 4$ rather than $1/4$?  What does the $4$ represent?

Comment: "If 40 people were to $\color{red}{\text{leave}}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have calculated the extra days with respect to $40$ people left, but the question asks you to consider $10$ remaining, which is why you got that incorrect figure. If $50$ people get through $1000$ litres of water a day then that means each person consumes $20$ litres of water a day. If $40$ people leave then that means there are $10$ people left, and since their rate of consumption doesn't change, it means they get through $200$ litres of water a day. With a supply of $1000$ litres, $10$ people will take $\frac{1000}{200}= 5$ days to drink it all. This is an increase of $4$ days.